# How to send email by php

Tags: php, sendmail, status

How to send an email with php is a very difficult quesion. When I use the function mail() to send an email, I
can't get the status of sending email correctly.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have already coded. It makes it easier for us to help you. Questions like yours without a given code example leave a bad taste.

Comment: You must post your attempts : http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the Zend Framework mail send option. It give you much more flexibility than the standard PHP mail() function.

More information can be found here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html